# DVI looks good, but why is HDMI horrible?

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, dvi

When I connect the the monitor to my PC using DVI, the output looks good. But when I connect the same monitor to the same PC using HDMI, the output is absolutely horrible - the picture and text comes out to be very grainy.

I am trying to use it for 1920x1080 (which shows up as the "recommended" option)

Here is my video card [Sapphire HD 6850 PCIE Video Card (100315L)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047ZGIUK)

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does your video card have separate digital paths for DVI and HDMI, or do they come from the same source?

Comment: Which OS? What's the native resolution of the monitor?  What's the resolution you are attempting to use?

Comment: I see two DVI connectors. Which are you using?

Comment: Is it possible your HDMI cable is damaged or that it's a problem with the monitor's HDMI input, not the video card? Try it with a different computer or different cable, if you can.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have a three-monitor setup. I am trying to use all 3 as DVI (2 from video card, 1 from motherboard)

Comment: that HDMI cable came from my DVD player which plays movies just fine.

Comment: Is the one that's giving you trouble the one that connects to the motherboard?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, it is connected to the video card shown in the picture

Comment: It happened for me before when the scaling or overscan setting is incorrect. Try to disable overscan if possible. IMHO DVI is much easier to work with because the video driver treats the output as a monitor (instead of an HDTV) by default and there is no need to tweak these settings.

Comment: I see you've purchased a non-nVidia graphics card and you're having trouble with it. Coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

Does that happen for all content, or when playing protected content only. It could be Windows not detecting the monitor as HDCP compliant (not able to perform HDCP handshake between the source and the display) and downgrading the video to low definition.